# how to paramaterise an existing exchange with brightway

Tags: brightway

I want to paramaterize exchanges of an existing brightway activity. in the [example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/Parameters%20-%20manual%20creation.ipynb) I've found the formula is defined for a new_exchange, can we do it for an existing one?

a practical example could be to redefine the fuel consumption as function of higher heating value and efficiency.

```
ex=[act for act in bw.Database('ei_34con') if 'natural gas' in act['name']
                                  and 'condensing' in act['name']
                                  and 'CH' in act['location']][0].copy()

ng_flow=[f for f in ex.technosphere() if ('natural gas' in f['name'])][0]


act_data=[{'name':'eff',
       'database':ex['database'],
       'code':ex['code'],
       'amount':0.95,
       'unit':''},
       {'name':'HHV',
       'database':ex['database'],
       'code':ex['code'],
       'amount':37,
       'unit':'MJ/m3'}]

bw.parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_data, "my group")
```

I naively tried

```
ng_flow['formula']='1/eff/HHV'

bw.parameters.add_exchanges_to_group("my group", ex)
ActivityParameter.recalculate_exchanges("my group")
```

but parameters did not update the amount of the exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close.

I reran your code and the line

```
bw.parameters.add_exchanges_to_group("my group", ex)
```

returns 0. This means no parameters were added.

However, if I *save* the exchange first:

```
 ng_flow.save()
 bw.parameters.add_exchanges_to_group("my group", ex)
```

returns 1, and

```
for exc in ex.technosphere():
    if "natural gas" in exc['name']:
        print(exc.amount, exc.input, exc.output)
```

Prints

```
0.028449502133712657 'market for natural gas, low pressure' (cubic meter, CH, None) 'heat production, natural gas, at boiler condensing modulating <100kW' (megajoule, CH, None)
```

Note that `ng_flow.as_dict()` does *not* show the updated value.

Comment: Thanks! any idea why *as_dict()* (or for that matter *ng_flow['amount]* does not show the update? .. I can always run again ng_flow=[f for f in ex.technosphere() if ('natural gas' in f['name'])][0] ... but it can cause some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

ng_flow.as_dict() or ng_flow['amount] does not show the update is probably because ng_flow is still linked to the not updated values. One needs to run "ng_flow=[f for f in ex.technosphere() if ('natural gas' in f['name'])][0]" again to update the values first.